# Resize a RAID 5 Partition

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

I'm moving my VG to a RAID, i have 3 disk 600GB, the VG is in the partition /dev/sdc2

```
/dev/sdc1 1G type linux <-- Boot partition
/dev/sdc2 599G type Linux LVM
```

One disk have the VG and with the others two i've created the RAID5

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 missing
pvcreate /dev/md0
vgextend VG_name /dev/md0
pvmove /dev/sdc2
vgreduce VG_name /dev/sdc2
pvremove /dev/sdc2
```

later I format the `/dev/sdc2` to type 'Linux raid autodetect' for add to the RAID but now i get

```
mdadm: /dev/sdc2 not large enough to join array
```

certainly completely forget the boot partition on device `/dev/sdc`

How  can solve for add /dev/sdc2 to the RAID. i think i need resize the partitions `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdd1` but i dont know how

Comment: In theory, this can be done (see [this guide](http://webapp5.rrz.uni-hamburg.de/SuSe-Dokumentation/manual/sles-manuals_en/manual/raidresize.html#resizedecr)). In practice, I would never even try but move my data out of the way and start over. A lot less stress, especially as your situation is even more complicated due to the LVM on top the RAID device.

Comment: In my experience, working with live data is quite stressful. Backup, resize, and recover = peace of mind

Comment: Add sdc2 back to VG, Move LVs sdc2.  Remove the MD device from the VG. Re-create MD with the correct partition sizes.  Leave enough space for the boot partition to exist on every drive.  Repeat your earlier procedure to migrate back to the RAID.

Comment: @Ravi has reason is  stressful but i can't stop the system. i'll try a some like Zoredache comment